# Flutter firestore isEqualTo 'timestamp' is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents with a **timestamp** field named 'date'. I want to query a single document with the specific 'date': 2024/02/29 00:00:00 UTC05.30.
So in Flutter, I'm trying to get that doc by using the following query

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('mycolloection').where('date', isEqualTo:  DateTime(2024,2,29,0,0,0,0,0),).snapshots(),),
```

but the above code does not retrieve any documents. So I played with isGreaterThan and isLesserThan for several hours and found out there is a hidden milliseconds value in the Firestore timestamp. So I have to give a milliseconds value as well. But this value is changing with different dates and it looks like a completely random number. Can anyone explain what is happening here...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, you store the `date` in Firestore in the following format:

```
2024/02/29 00:00:00 GMT05.30
```

Which is not quite correct. Such a field can exist inside a document in Firestore only as a string. I'm saying that because `GMT (Greenwich Mean Time)` is a timezone and the timestamps in Firestore don't encode timezones. The timezone of the Firestore timestamp is UTC.

If you need to work with date and time, then you should use a [Firestore Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html), which is a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) in Firestore. So once you set the field with the correct data type, you can then perform a query.

Please also note that when you call `where()` you have to pass a timestamp object and **not** a `DateTime`. If you do so, you'll never get the desired results.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question, it should be UTC instead of GMT. I resolved the issue by setting date programatically via flutter. If I use firebase console to set the date then use 'isEqualTo timestamp' to get the document it will not work. But if I set the same date on firestore with same time  with flutter it works somehow. Could be a bug, could be a something on my side. Will explore later. Thanks for your help. @Frank

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use the `isEqualTo` operation to match a timestamp, you'll have to match the exact timestamp that is stored in the database. To make that feasible, you'll need to ensure that you store the timestamp with 0 milliseconds **and 0 microseconds** too.

For example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

The `today` variable will not have just the date part, with all time parts set to `0`.